# Discord.py error message: discord.ext.commands.bot: Privileged message content intent is missing

Tags: python, discord.py

Can someone help me? I keep getting this error message when I try to start up my discord bot.

```
[2022-08-23 14:32:12] [WARNING ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.
```

This is the code for the bot and after this is just commands and events and client.run(My_Token)

```
import os
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
from discord.utils import get
from itertools import cycle
import json
import random


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.typing = True
intents.presences = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "?", intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')
status = cycle(["Minecraft", "Roblox", "Yo-Kai Watch"])
```

Comment: Set `intents.message_content = True` and enable the message contents intent in the discord developer page for your bot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got to change

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
```

to

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
```

It was an unmentioned change in the v2.0 discord.py update. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html

Comment: Setting the intents to all() will cause an error if the bot account has not been granted all intents. A better answer to the question is to explicitly set the message_content intent to True, as other answers and comments have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.0/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content

just add this line

```py
intent.message_content = True #v2
```

with default is not enabled (and y dont view why is not enabled dy default)