# Discord Ticket Status Bot - Code not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

There is something wrong with the code of which I am unsure, it seems to be logging in to the bot, but it will not send the message to the channel I have requested. I have updated permissions on both the developer portal, and establish the guild on the code, alongside the permissions in the server.

It returns as:
Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.guilds = True
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
commands.Bot

ticket_channel_id = '1217573242009817138'
open_tickets_count = 5  

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == ticket_channel_id:
        # Assign the channel object to the channel variable
        channel = message.channel
        ticket_status = ''
        if open_tickets_count < 10:
            ticket_status = 'Low'
        elif 10 <= open_tickets_count <= 15:
            ticket_status = 'Moderate'
        else:
            ticket_status = 'Busy'

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        day = now.weekday()  # 0 (Monday) to 6 (Sunday)
        hour = now.hour  # 0 to 23

        if 1 <= day <= 5:  # Monday to Friday
            if 9 <= hour < 17:
                response_time = 'Slow'
            elif hour < 21:
                response_time = 'Fast'
            else:
                response_time = 'Response unlikely until next day'
        elif day == 6:  # Saturday
            if hour < 10:
                response_time = 'Slow'
            elif hour < 18:
                response_time = 'Fast'
            elif hour < 21:
                response_time = 'Moderate'
            else:
                response_time = 'Unlikely response until next day'
        else:  # Sunday
            response_time = 'Responses unlikely'

        response_message = f'Ticket Status: {ticket_status}\nResponse Time: {response_time}'
        await channel.send(response_message)  # Use the channel variable to send the message


  
    try:
        await channel.send(response_message)
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
        print(f'Failed to send message: {e}')

bot.run('mybot-token')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line:

```
intents.message_content = True
```

[Source: mousetail comment to OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73458847/discord-py-error-message-discord-ext-commands-bot-privileged-message-content-i)