Discord Python can not find the attribute "event" inside of "bot"
Look at my code down here /
This is the output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Games\Coding\tickets.py", line 8, in 
@client.event
^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'discord.client' has no attribute 'event'
Code:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.bot

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready to execute action")

What is going wrong here?

It's commands.Bot and you need to call it with command_prefix parameter.
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Make something with the bot")

client.run('BOT_TOKEN')


Ty very much the bot is online now ❤️
But I still get this error code:
2024-04-06 15:20:33 WARNING  discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.

@Thatonenoobcoder you can look at here about the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73458847/discord-py-error-message-discord-ext-commands-bot-privileged-message-content-i

You can mark my answer as solved the question if it solves your problem, thank you.
